# getting an a link to open in an iframe on a new page

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Really hoping someone can help me. I have a client that wants an alink that is generated in his site (deals site) to open in a fresh window within an iframe. I have done all the styling for the site but this is really foxing me. This is how the link currently looks

```
$deal_link = get_post_meta( $offer_id, 'deal_link', true );
if( !empty( $deal_link ) ){
    echo '<a href="'.esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'rd' => get_the_ID() ),     
get_permalink() ) ).'" class="btn" target="iframe_a" id="show_button" 
rel="nofollow">'.__( 'BUY NOW', 'couponxl' ).'</a>';
```

I currently have it opening a popup on that page with the iframe inside but this isn't the best fix.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you're opening a new window, why use IFRAME? Perhaps a simple

<A HREF="http://www.???.html" target="_blank"

Comment: it isn't that, the content needs to be pulled into a branded page so an iframe in the center with header and footer. The iframe content is coming from a different site